# Conditional rendering and inline IF doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I have two problems:

1. the conditional rendering is not working well on Statistics component
2. inline IF on the line 46 didn't work so I commented out. I checked the values with typeof jc func and all values are numbers

Please let me know if you spot what I've done wrong.

Thanks a lot!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const Feedback = (props) => (
  <button onClick={props.handleFeedback}>{props.text}</button>
)

const Statistics = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  if (props.total.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div>empty</div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>all {props.total}</p>
      <p>average {props.average}</p>
      <p>positive {props.positive}</p>
  </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)

  const setToGood = (newValue) => () => {
    setGood(newValue)
  }

  const setToNeutral = (newValue) => () => {
    setNeutral(newValue)
  }

  const setToBad = (newValue) => () => {
    setBad(newValue)
  }

  const total = good + neutral + bad;
  const average = (good - bad) / total
  const positive =  (good / total * 100 === 0 ) ? '' : (good / total * 100)
  console.log(positive);
 

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>give feedback</h1>
      <Feedback handleFeedback={setToGood(good +1)} text="good" />
      <Feedback handleFeedback={setToNeutral(neutral +1)} text="neutral" />
      <Feedback handleFeedback={setToBad(bad +1)} text="bad" />
      <h1>statisctics</h1>
      <p>good {good}</p>
      <p>neutral {neutral}</p>
      <p>bad {bad}</p>
      <Statistics total={total} average={average} positive={positive}/>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Please dont upload pictures of code. It makes it harder for us to work with.

Comment: In your statistics, can you console.log(props) and share the output with us?

Comment: props.total is type of number, so the condition never applies. Try props.total === 0

Comment: @JohnS here is what I got from console.log
{total: 0, average: NaN, positive: NaN}
average: NaN
positive: NaN
total: 0
__proto__: Object

Comment: @Norby please do what Goldwave has told to you

Comment: OK I added the code, thank you!

Comment: Could you explain problem #1, I am unsure where you are having trouble, You also got rid of your code for problem #2

Comment: @JohnS 1. i want to display statistics only when the feedback (good, nutral, bad) is added. 2. yes I changed the code a bit positive variable, but I haven't solved the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `IF` don't use `props.total.length` as total is of `number` type not string.